# Can one configure gdb/ddd to never step into certain functions?

Tags: debugging, gdb, skip, ddd-debugger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing GDB from stepping into a function (or file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133365/preventing-gdb-from-stepping-into-a-function-or-file)

I have some infrastructure C++ code (containers, memory managers etc.) and I want the debugger to never step into those methods while debugging an application issue.

I know this can be done with Visual Studio and I have used that before on other projects:

[Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visua)

Is this at all possible with gdb or ddd?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133365/preventing-gdb-from-stepping-into-a-function-or-file) question.
See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448426/how-to-avoid-entering-librarys-source-files-while-debugging-in-qt-creator-with-g/1475262#1475262) answer. Short answer: no.

Comment: The actual question is about not stepping into a specific function during a debugging session. What I am looking for is for 'blacklisting' a whole list of functions. But you are right it seems that GDB can not do it (yet).