# Avoid stepping into c++ std header files in Visual Studio 2008 Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visua)

Good Morning,

I'm looking for a way to tell the debugger to avoid stepping into some header files that are of no interest to me when debugging my code.

Example: When I have a std::string as a parameter of a function and I just want to step into **my** function, I first fall into the stl string code. But I guess I will never find my bugs in the stl header files and therefore I want to tell VS to ignore these files completely.

Is there a way to do it? This would save a lot of Shift-F11+F11 keystrokes. :-)

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no solution to exclude header files.
You can, however, define code that will always be stepped over.
See: [Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visua)