# Visual Studio 2015 Debug: How to stay within my own program only

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm a beginner at c++, and whenever I write a trivial program in VS2015, and try to debug it, the debugger takes me through every single detail of every standard library function that I used, with 20-30 break points between the statements that I actually wrote.

I can't debug at all this way, and I'd really like to know if there's a way to turn this feature off.
I want to debug MY code, not the library code.

Comment: there's nothing stopping you from stepping out, running to cursor, running until next breakpoint have you investigated those?

Comment: `with 20-30 break points between the statements that I actually wrote` Are you sure that you're jumping to next *break point* rather than actually just jumping to the next statement (as in "jump in")?

Comment: In settings there should be "Just my Code" option, but I am not sure that it works for C++. Otherwise you should stop using "step-in" because that takes you deeper on the callstack, while 'step-over" keeps you on the same level of callstack.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). Consider options like the breakpoints or the "step over".

Comment: I find "Run to cursor" very useful also.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is that you could think about using the "Step Into Specific" or not step into Functions using the registry key like this case:

[Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visua)