# Visual studio 2015 . How to *not* step in certain functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I'd like to configure the VS2015 debugger so that when I'm stepping in into some code (F11), it steps through certain functions .

For example, let's say there is a template class SmartPointer which has an overloaded member -> .

If I have the following statement :

```
SmartPointer<SomeClass> ptr;
/* initialize ptr */

ptr->method();
```

The debugger will step into SmartPointer::operator->, exit, then the into method().
I'd like to directly step into method().

Is this possible ?

EDIT : The so called duplicate isn't one because it doesn't work with vs2013 or 2015

Comment: Not sure if there is a good way to do this.  I typically set a break point on the first line of the function and run to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visu)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. As NathanOlivier said, the better way is to set a breakpoint in you method()...

Comment: Yes you can https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I actually found the solution. You have to edit as an administrator:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter

or

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter

depending if you're under a 64 or 32 bit machine. The add a line like

```
<Function><Name>SomeFunction</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
```

HTH

Comment: Instead of doing it create your own natstepfilter in %userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Visualizers

Comment: Thanks for the hint !

Comment: @Dinaiz, since it has been resolved, please mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members:)